# TypeError when trying to call JSON data via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass some JSON data from a PHP page to javascript, but it's not working.

The PHP page `test-call.php` outputs some minimal test data like so:

```
<?php
$username = 'MyValue';
$data = array('retid' => $username);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The calling page loads jquery `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>` in the `<head>` and has javascript as recommended [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520119/passing-json-data-from-a-php-page-as-a-javascript-variable) like this:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'test-call.php',
dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        var retid = response.data.retid;
        console.log(retid);
    },
});
</script>
```

However, running the javascript results in an error described by console as"

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.data.retid')`

What is wrong here?

Comment: `$.getJSON('test-call.php', function(response) { console.log(response); });` The next step is to look at console output and go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response` is the data, so `response.data` is undefined. You can access to your data using `response.retid`:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test-call.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        var retid = response.retid;
        console.log(retid);
    },
});
</script>
```

Comment: I find that I get a 404 in console however, if the url has a query string to enable it to look up its values in a database (as in `test-call.php?id=123`).  Is it possible to alter the code to accommodate URLs with query strings?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it is the presence of the query string in the URL that's causing the 404.  It looks like it is the fact that test-call.php does a DB lookup.  If I don't do the DB lookup in test-call.php, and just hard-code the output data, the AJAX call works.  But if I do allow test-call.php to look up (whether or not I include the query string in the AJAX code), I get the 404.

Comment: Ah - sorry - it was neither. Sorry for the false alarm - it was an unrelated uncommented line in test-call.php for login purposes. Syscall's code works fine.